# How To Get First Item of Array

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have a windows phone project about news from media.
On this project, I have a panaroma item. In my first screeen, I get the news from my web API.

I use longlist selector to get these news but I want to put first/hot/newest new on the top with big picture of it and the text. But I couldn't gave the source rightly on my grid and `LongListSelector` at the same time.

In short, I want to list my news "one under the other" and the newest/first new will be big pictured on the top.

Here is what I've tried;

**MAINPAGE.XAML**

```
<!--Panorama item one-->
<phone:PanoramaItem Header="Haberler" Foreground="DarkGreen">
    <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Background="White">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">


                        <Grid x:Name="HeadNew">
                            <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock14" Text="{Binding Path=TITLE}"  TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="20,0" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeLarge}" Foreground="Black"/>
                            <Border Width="400" Height="250">
                                <Border.Background>
                                    <ImageBrush Stretch="Uniform" ImageSource="{Binding Path=MF658370_IMAGE}"/>
                                </Border.Background>
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>

            <phone:LongListSelector x:Name="MainLongListSelector" Background="White" Margin="-20,0,0,0" Height="Auto" Loaded="MainLongListSelectorLoaded" SelectionChanged="MainLongListSelectorSelectionChanged" toolkit:TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled="True">
                <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="12,2,0,4" Height="Auto" Width="Auto">
                            <Border Width="126" Height="70">
                                <Border.Background>
                                    <ImageBrush Stretch="Uniform" ImageSource="{Binding Path=MF12670_IMAGE}"/>
                                </Border.Background>
                            </Border>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock1" Text="{Binding Path=TITLE}" Margin="10,0" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeMedium}" Foreground="Black" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
            </phone:LongListSelector>

        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
</phone:PanoramaItem>
```

Here is the MAINPAGE.XAML.CS

```
private void MainLongListSelectorLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    const string url = "MY_WEB_API_URL";
    var hWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    hWebRequest.Method = "GET";
    hWebRequest.BeginGetResponse(MainLongListSelectorLoadCompleted, hWebRequest);
}

private void MainLongListSelectorLoadCompleted(IAsyncResult arr)
{
    var request = (HttpWebRequest)arr.AsyncState;
    var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(arr);
    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        _json = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        Headlines = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FanatikApiAll.RootObject>(_json);
    }
    Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
    {
        MainLongListSelector.ItemsSource = Headlines.Headline;
    });

    Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
    {
        HeadNew.DataContext = Headlines.Headline;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since HeadNew isn't a list control, you need to assign only the item you need, not the whole list. For instance, to get the first item if any:

```
Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
{
    HeadNew.DataContext = Headlines.Headline.FirstOrDefault();
});
```

Comment: @kgms21 Add using `using System.Linq;`